# License information cache not cleared after sign out

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

In my app I use `CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses` to retrieve current user's info from store to check if there's a active license available. Problem is that when the user signs out from Windows Store - `CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses` still returns active licenses even after PC restart.

Is it possible to clear active licenses after Windows Store sign out?

Comment: I don't know if you know this but this system is there in order to allow user to use the application without an internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you sign out of the Microsoft Store, you are still logged in to the Microsoft Account that has the license into the system itself. And furthermore - it is possible to temporarily login into a different account in the Microsoft Store, download an app and then sign out - the app will still work. The license is tied to the user who downloaded the app and it does not matter if she is signed into the Microsoft Store app itself after that.